# Ajax takes value of first radio button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have two different set of radio buttons. Under this I am triggering the passing of value to another file when the second set of radio button is triggered. But the issue is that while passing the value jquery takes value of first radio button in the second set. No matter whichever button you select.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sub_category_form_cat_1").click(function()
  {
        var main_cat=$("#main_cat:checked").val();
        var sub_cat_form1=$("input:radio[name='sub-category_form_cat_1']:checked").val();
        $.ajax
        ({
            data: {'cat':main_cat,'sub_cat':sub_cat_form1},
            url: "ajax_files/events-select.php",
            type: 'GET',                
            success: function(data) 
            {
                $("#displayedresults").html(data);
                $('#loading_spinner').hide();
                $('#loading_text').hide();
                $('#loading_row').hide();
                $('#displayedresults').show();
                //$('.button_export').show();
                //$("a.button_export").attr("href", string);
            }
        });
        return false;
  });
});
```

```
<tr><td>Category:</td><td>
    <input type="radio" name="category_form_cat_1" value="Adults" id="main_cat" />&nbsp;Adults &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="category_form_cat_1" value="Kids" id="main_cat" />&nbsp;Kids</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub-Category:</td><td>
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Dance" id="sub_category_form_cat_1"/>&nbsp;Dance&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Fitness" id="sub_category_form_cat_1"/>&nbsp;Fitness
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Workshop" id="sub_category_form_cat_1"/>&nbsp;Workshop&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Events" id="sub_category_form_cat_1"/>&nbsp;Events</td></tr>
```

Comment: Only 'Dance' one allows me to trigger the function. Rest of the Three options i.e. Fitness, Workshop doesn't trigger the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id's are really for single and unique tags, what you really want to do is to give all of the radios class names of "sub_category_form_cat_1" and then use $(".sub_category_form_cat_1").click(function(){});

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one element with a given `id`. This will always return the first element with that `id`. You need to reference the element within the form

```
var main_cat = $("input[name='category_form_cat_1']:checked").val();
```

Since this isn't working, let's try something different

```
<tr><td>Category:</td><td id="maincat>
    <input type="radio" name="category_form_cat_1" value="Adults" />&nbsp;Adults &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="category_form_cat_1" value="Kids" />&nbsp;Kids</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub-Category:</td><td id="subcat">
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Dance" />&nbsp;Dance&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Fitness" />&nbsp;Fitness
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Workshop" />&nbsp;Workshop&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="sub-category_form_cat_1" value="Events" />&nbsp;Events
</td></tr>
```

And for your JS

```
var main_cat = $("#maincat").children("input:checked").val();
```

Comment: I tried changing the code with your suggested one
But till now it is taking the value of the first radio button in the second set. i.e. Everytime i select Fitness radio button nothing happens and when i select Dance then, it returns Dance.

`var main_cat = $("input[name='category_form_cat_1']:checked").val();
var sub_cat_form1 = $("input[name='sub-category_form_cat_1']:checked").val();`